# How to set up query arguments to `link_to` mojolicious helper?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I want to pass arguments for link generated by `link_to` helper:

```
%= link_to 'Change password' =>  'auth_remind', { login => $login }
```

but this does not work.

How to set up query arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not documented yet, but in default `welcome.html.ep` we can found:

```
%= link_to 'click here' => url_for
```

So we can do next:

```
%= link_to 'Change password' =>  url_for( 'auth_remind' )->query( login => $login )
```

If we need to set up some arguments for route we may:

```
%= link_to 'Change password' =>  url_for( 'auth_remind', { format => 'txt' } )->query( login => $login )
```